# Asking the user for settings when enabling an Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am working on an alexa skill which uses an external web service which requires an API key.

I can't find for the life of me where I can add this property in so that when the user enables the Alexa skill (I haven't got as far as publishing yet but I assume there is a property I can set somewhere as well for testing) they can add their API key and I receive this within my node.js lambda function and extract it and use it for my post request to the web service.

I know there is an Amazon Account Linking Service, but the web service I am using doesn't support this type of login I believe, their API is only accessed by sending a header containing the API key. Therefore I need a way for the user to be able to store somewhere their API key so I can then post this to the web service from the lambda code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on how you expect the user to 'add their API key'.

The only built-in UI is the cards that your skill can push to a user but these are very limited and can't request information from the user.

Amazon does not show the user any sort of configurable settings for the skills.

And you have noted account-linking and that it does not address your needs.

So you could either ask the user to say the API key, which would be much too error prone unless it is unusually short, or you will need to direct the user (probably via a card) to your own website where they will provide their API key.

Comment: Ah that's annoying, I thought some skills had their own settings page. That's going to rather over complicate things as my plan apparently isn't going to work

Comment: If they have their own setting page when they implemented and hosted it themselves, and shepherded the user to it.